# Before-Save Flow in separate transaction from Apex + after-save Flow?

Tags: trigger, visual-workflow, transaction

I expected before-save Flow + Apex triggers + after-save Flow to be a single transaction.  However, when set Debug Logs, **I get two entries**.  One contains my contact before-save Flow, then a second entry contains managed package Apex activity (NPSP) + my contact after-save Flow.

Why would this happen?  If a before-save Flow is in a separate transaction, how can it be rolled back if the after-save Flow fails?  On the other hand, if everything is still one transaction, why are there two debug log entries?

UPDATE: one odd thing is that the log files don't have any entries for "entering managed package" like I usually see.  I know the managed package Apex is running, and there are profile entries for that namespace in the log, but there are no generic lines indicating the expected managed package activity.

Comment: What do the debug log entries look like?

Comment: Oddly there are no log entries indicating managed package activity.  I updated my post with details.